# Structured Illumination Microscopy Diffraction Grating Spacing How It Scales From SLM To Object Plane

Tags: optics, diffraction, microscopy

I'm trying to understand better how to scale the pattern one generates on the Structured Light Modulator (SLM) into the object plane.

I've been viewing various papers like the following one, but I always get stuck when understanding how they turn a repeating pattern on the SLM with period of ~87 um (see below) into a sinusoidal with repeating period of 193 nm (as stated in the paper), if the only magnifying component is a 63x objective.

I keep thinking that the period should be ~87 um / 63 = ~1.38 um.
But that isn't the case. Do L4 (focal length 150 mm) and TL-Illu (focal length 125 mm) scale the image before it goes into the 63x objective? Or is there something else going on I'm miss-understanding/overlooking?

If the two lens' after the "Mask" are responsible, is there anyway to confirm calculate the additional ~7 times reduction in the period of the repeating pattern based on the data provided in the paper?

**Update 2018-04-14:** 
It looks like perhaps I lack an understanding of angular magnification as lens 3 with focal length of 750 mm when divided by lens 4 with focal length of 150 mm gives an angular magnification of 5. This would take my calculated value of ~1.38 um down to ~0.276 um. I'm not really sure if this is whats going on though as it still doesn't match the quoted 193 nm from the paper.

**Update 2018-04-26:**
I managed to test out the lens arrangement using some simulation software and find the distances between the lens' that result in the value as detailed in the paper. As I suspected in my prior update it is related to lens 3 with 750 mm and lens 4 with 150 mm focal lengths. I'm not sure how to use simple lens formulas to calculate the magnification when the light between two lens is collimated. Anyways as McGrew said "If the zero-order is filtered out and only the two first-order components are used, the spatial frequency is effectively doubled.", then on top of that we get 5x manification from lens 3 and 4. This gives us roughly 87 um / 10 = 8.7 um which when divided by 63x (objective power) is equal to 138 nm which is somewhat close to the 193 nm from the paper. Since I don't really understand how to compute the magnification using angular magnification or why the discrepancy between 193 nm and 138 nm I don't feel confident answering my own question but otherwise I can move on. Thanks McGrew for your help.

== remainder of original question ==

https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-22-17-20663

My computed period of ~87 um is based on the SLM pixel pitch of 13.62 um and the fact the sample patterns in the paper appear to repeat approximately every 6.4 pixels (as measured perpendicular to the fringes). Giving 13.62 um * 6.4 = ~87 um.

Here are some further excerpts from the paper.

> The excitation laser (442 nm/70 mW) is controlled by an acousto-optical tunable filter (AOTFnC-VIS, AA Opto-Electronic, France). A beam collimator consisting of a pinhole (Ø= 25μm, Thorlabs, USA) and two lenses (f1 = 35 mm and f2 = 100 mm, Thorlabs, USA) achieves mode cleaning and beam expansion.
>
> In the setup, the beam diameter is roughly one third of the shorter side of
>   the SLM.
>   [I've computed this as diameter = 13.62*1024/3 um = 4648.96 um]
>
> The spatial frequency domain of the displayed grating is projected into the BFP of lens 3 (f3 = 750 mm, Thorlabs, USA)
>
> Lens 4 (f4 = 150 mm, Thorlabs, USA) and the illumination tube lens (fTL−Illu = 125 mm, Thorlabs, USA), image the pupil plane into the BFP of the objective. The objective (Plan-Apochromat ×63/1.4 oil DIC, Zeiss, Germany) generates the two-beam interference in the sample plane. The grating constant in the sample is 193 nm. The field of view in sample space is 19.5 × 13.8 µm².

Comment: Have you applied the Lensmaker's equation in your calculations?  As long as you know the distances between all the components including the SLM, the lenses, and the sample, the Lensmaker's equation should give you the right results.  Although the last excerpt refers to two-beam interference, the effect amounts to imaging the SLM onto the object IF the optical system uses the zero-order and first-order diffraction from the SLM.  If the zero-order is filtered out and only the two first-order components are used, the spatial frequency is effectively doubled.

Comment: Hey S. McGrew, Thanks! Unfortunately they don't give the distances between the lens' in any of the papers I've read just the lens' focal lengths. I tried experimenting with my DLP projector I use for TV and I was able to decrease the size of the projected image by using a 6.5 cm focal length lens followed by a 28 cm focal length lens. I think I was just getting confused because the lens are always focusing at infinity in the papers (because they want to block 0 order and 2+ order harmonics). So I got stuck when trying to apply the thin lens formula.

Comment: cont'd: I will do some more reading to better understand how to use the thin lens formula when you are placing objects at the focal plane and focusing to infinity and then doing the reverse right after.

Comment: Added an update relating to angular magnification with the f3 750 mm and f4 150 mm lens. I will need to read more to better understand this.